# How can I reduce this Query's operation time with Indexes?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have a really simple query and a pool of 8718 registers, the run time for it is approximately 7 seconds, and I don't understand the reason behind it. I've tried using Indexes utilizing the document type, state and reference (basically the variables from the WHERE clause). And even tho the index is utilized, nor the cardinality or cost are reduced whatsoever.

I can't see any way to reduce the query size by itself, so I'm guessing it has to be an Index issue. I'd appreciate any kind of help.

```
    SELECT TELEPHONE AS telephone, 
    GROUP AS group, 
    UPPER(GROUPNAME) AS groupName, 
    RECEIPTID AS receiptId, 
    sum(CHARGED) AS charged, 
    sum(PAID) AS paid, 
    YEAR as year, 
    MONTH as month 

    FROM PERMANENT_TABLE 
    where DOC_TYPE in('0', '01', '04') 
    and state = X 
    and reference = XXXXX
    GROUP BY TELEPHONE, RECEIPTID, GROUP, GROUPNAME, YEAR, 
    MONTH;
```

Cardinality/Cost for:

Group by: 8718/7893
Index: 30741/6168

Thank you for your time, if any additional information is required, please let me know.

Comment: Which WHERE clause condition is most restrictive? If most documents are of one of the three listed types, an index with first key column DOC_TYPE will not be helpful. If there are few rows with reference = XXXXX, you want that column as first index key. It's hard to say more without the full table structure, but my guess is to use an index (reorder keys depending on specificity of where clause conditions) with key (reference, state, DOC_TYPE) that also includes the selected columns as non-key columns. Also be sure no implicit type conversions are taking place in the WHERE clause.

Comment: In this particular case, all of the doc types are 0, so i guess for testing purposes it can be removed from the index, I will try, as you say indexing the reference as the first clause.

Comment: The cardinality shown in the explain plan is the estimated number of rows that will be returned, so that number will stay the same regardless of any indexes or lack of them. The cost is the optimiser's estimate for resource usage. It is best not to rely on it as an indicator of performance. Also, do you really want doc types `'0', '01', '04'` or do you want `0, 1, 4`? What is a pool of 8718 registers?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I didn't really know the difference, and with the pool, I actually meant 8718 rows of information. The doc types that I need are indeed 01 and 04, as that is the predefined format; thank you for spending your time helping.

Answer (score 1):

The optimal index for your query is probably:  `PERMANENT_TABLE(state, reference, DOC_TYPE)`.

The `state` and `reference` columns should be the first two, but can be in either order.

You could include the other columns, but that probably wouldn't be a big win in terms of performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried this as you said, but I had some trouble having the query utilize the Index, since it just kept going for a full search. I managed to reduce the time a little bit by using the month and year as an additional filter, but I still have my doubt with Indexes and how to really make them work on cases like this